# PySide: QTimer needs QApplication to work?

Tags: qt, pyside

Just started learning PySide and is having problem with QTimer

I have this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from PySide.QtCore import QThread;
from classes import Updater;

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = QThread();
    thread.start();

    update = Updater();
    update.moveToThread(thread);
    update.run();
```

and this

```
class Updater(QObject):
    def update_mode(self):
        #do something
        pass;

    def run(self):
        timer = QTimer();
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_mode);
        timer.start(10);
```

I want my script to do some work periodically using QTimer (wanted to try QSystemAlignedTimer but that looks even more complicated to me for now...). Not sure what is wrong at the moment because I am getting this error

```
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QTimer`, along with all other event based classes, need there to be a `QApplication` instance.

In:

```
thread = QThread();
thread.start();

update = Updater();
update.moveToThread(thread);
update.run();
```

First of all, *get rid of the semicolons*. Python programmers don't like those.
If you take a close look at what your code is doing, you are making a `QThread`, starting it, making an `Updater`, moving it to the thread, running it, and ending the program. There is no command here telling Python to keep the program running, so it ends, and the `QThread` complains about being destroyed.

What you should do is make a `QApplication`, with something like

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

and the call `app.exec_()` to start it. In this case, this is essentially equivalent to `time.sleep(9999999999...)`, but what it actually does is it processes events (signals/slots) endlessly. With `time.sleep(9999999999...)`, `QTimers` will never do anything when they time out.

As a `QApplication` is an infinite loop, you will have to manually exit within your code.

Comment: QApplication from PySide.QtGui? but my app doesn't need a GUI

Comment: No idea what happens, but it works for now lol so not gonna change it until I learn more about Qt